# Cell Imageview with Gesture - Which image was tapped?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, imageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a UITableview with cells which are displayed with an image, a labeltext and a detailTextLabel. 
The cell.imageview is configured with a UITapGestureRecognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(infoImageTapped:)];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[cell.imageView setGestureRecognizers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:tap]];
```

The Method "infoImageTapped" is triggered fine. Now I want to know which image (to be more specific, which imageNamed) was tapped.

I tried the following code:

```
UIImageView *theTappedImageView = (UIImageView *)tap.view;
NSLog(@"Gesture Tag: %@", theTappedImageView.description);
```

In the NSLog-Window: The imageNamed (*.png) is displayed but I don't know how to write this information into
a NSString variable.

I need the imagenamed (or a reference to the original image in the cell) to open a AlertView with the image.

Thanks in advance
Florian

Comment: `theTappedImageView.image` should give you the image set in the image view. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: OMG. I swear that I tried that already. Thank you @Amar, works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)infoImageTapped :(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *) gesture.view;
   NSLog(@"Gesture Tag: %@", image.description);

}
```

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: Thank you @Rushabh :-) I tried that but i didn't work the first time. Anyway, now it works like charm :)